# Sort list with JS or a new query?

Tags: javascript, mysql

After a sql query, I echo the results in a page. There are not so many rows (say 50-100), and four columns. I want to add a button on top of each column for users to sort the results according to their needs. It can be done with JS or performing a new search in the database (with `order by xxx`).

Which one is better? Advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Depends ... on the data, on the site, on the way you update the result, on how fast the database is, on how it's sorted, if it's sorted often and can be cached, on ..... just about everything.

Comment: I have to agree with @adeneo, most of this is based on the very specific details of your setup and work load. Many times in development a solution is attempted and later redone because there is room for improvement.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So "a priori" is not completely horrible to perform a new query. I'm still newby, I want to know opinions before starting to code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, each query to the database requires more memory and cpu power, even with a lower amout of rows.
The cost to perform a ordering on the client side (javascript) is less than the cost to perform multiple queries, and adding order by to the total cost increases it definetly.

So. I Would suggest reorder using JS.

Comment: Yep, your suggestion sounds logical. I wil try that (damn!, I feel more confortable with php than JS...)

Comment: Well, me too. But its just a metter of be used with. The important thing is to know the logic. How to do that (which functions, bla bla bla) you discover on google. You just know how (using logic) you would do it.

Comment: Done. I was reluctant to mark as "Solved" because is an opinion, not a real problem. Anyway, it was my fault for posting such a question. (By the way, finally I use DataTables). Thanks!